# how test that the connection works in Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm looking for a way to test if a connection is working or not with Doctrine 2.

As in my application users can change by themselves the information connections, I want to check if the user has entered the right login and password.

How can I do that?

I tried to put this code into a try/catch block :

```php
try{
    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager() ;
    $repository = $entityManager->getRepository('Authentification\Entity\User');
    $userToIdentify = $repository->findOneBy(array('login' => $this->_username, 'password' => $this->_password));
}catch(Exception $e){
    $code = Result::FAILURE ;
    $identity = "unknow" ;
    $messages = array(
       "message" => "Wrong login/password combination",
    ) ;
}
```

The problem is that even if the information connection is correct, I cannot catch the exception.

Otherwise I get the following error :

```html
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException'
  with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template 
  &quot;layout/layout&quot;; resolver could not resolve to a file' in C:\xampp\htdocs\poemsV3\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php:451 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\poemsV3\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(203): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer-&gt;render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\poemsV3\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(128): Zend\View\View-&gt;render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #2 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy-&gt;render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\poemsV3\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(469): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\poemsV3\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventMa in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\poemsV3\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php</b> on line <b>451</b><br />
```

Do you have any idea in how I could test if the connection works?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do not use the `EntityManager` directly. You can instead use following to check the connection parameters:

```php
try {
    $entityManager->getConnection()->connect();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // failed to connect
}
```

That's sadly the only real way to check if something went wrong, since the exception type changes depending on the driver you use.

For the other exception (the view-related one) you simply have to adjust your view scripts path. I suggest you to keep the [skeleton application module](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/tree/zf/release-2.1.0/module/Application) enabled so that the default layout is always there: you can [override it at any time](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#configuration).

Comment: May i ask - why do you use a backslash on Exception? I've never seen it this way. Is this somehow required to ensure namespace integrity?

Comment: @SquareCat \ means root namespace. This is required in case you've set a namespace directive in your file to make sure the PHP Exception class is used and not one from your namespace.

Comment: Note: since DBAL 2.5, `Connection#ping()` is available.

Comment: I was trying to use this try catch block and the only way I got it to pass is removing the ->connect(). I have Doctrine 2.4.8 installed with Symfony/yaml 2.

Comment: `Connection::ping()` despite the naming is not really suitable for testing the connection as before the test it tries to reconnect to the database catching possible exceptions.

Comment: `connect()` is marked as `@internal` and will stop working in DBAL 4.0. Its successor seems to be `getNativeConnection()`

Answer (score 5):

You can use.

```php
$cnx = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();

$cnx->isConnected() ? 
  'Connected' : 
  'not connected';
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answer from @mrDjouk, this is something to note.

```php
    $conn = DriverManager::getConnection($dbConfig);
    print_r(['$conn1' => $conn->isConnected()]);
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $myTable";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);

    print_r(['$conn2' => $conn->isConnected()]);
```

`$conn1` is false and
`$conn2` is true

doctrine/dbal: 3.7.2, postgresql 16, php 8.3